# Hero Image - Don't know how to articulate this

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is have the background image fill the entire page, but with the ability to scroll down and not have the image go on forever. If I add the image to a div background-size cover dose not work, I need to add a height and width which dose not seem ideal.

```css
body {
 background-image: url("http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/66/90/zq7i3T.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Luke Hayes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
 <h1>Some testing text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle. So that i can understand what do you want?

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: @Raziasultana https://jsfiddle.net/4ujx31aa/ I put the H1 a few thousand pixels down to show what I mean by the background image going on forever.

Answer (score 0):

apply the body style to the hero div, and make it fill the viewport (height: 100vh)

```css
      .hero {
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url("http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/66/90/zq7i3T.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
      }

      h1 {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 2000px;
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="hero">
<h1>Some testing text</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: That's much close to what I'm going for, I'm stuck with a ~50px gap at the top though even after CSS reset https://jsfiddle.net/20dgbyb0/ I just did this the other day and didn't need to use height and got what I wanted, it's weird. Thanks for taking a look at it though :)

Comment: @LukeHayes the gap is caused by the H1 margins, just remove them using `margin:0` and you won't see the gap anymore